# How to use Multi-Select with iReport with Stored Procedure in Report Query?

Tags: stored-procedures, jasper-reports, ireport, multi-select

I'm using *iReport 5.0* attempting to develop reports for *SQL Server 2008R2* back end.

Enabling the user to mix/match selections from a list (multi-select) is important.
The multi-select works well if the query in the *iReport* is SQL or has a view as source -- e.g.
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/529890/how-do-multi-select-ireport-36

In this case, the `WHERE $X{IN,<colname>,<iReport parameter>}` works fine to enable muti-select:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/519185/using-x-query-parameter-type-not-supporte

However, I'd like to pass all the inputs to an *SQL Server stored procedure* in the *iReport* Query.  In this case, the single valued inputs all work fine -- but I have been unable to figure out how to use muti-select -- the `$X{}` does not seem to work and otherwise -- since the *iReport* multi-select parameter must be defined as *java.util.Collection* -- I get the "Parameter type not supported in query".

Can anyone point out what I am missing, or suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

OK -- I have come a bit further on this and can show what worked for me:
To get array SP parameters to work (ie query using a WHERE IN() clause where all the comma-separated elements of the input parameter go into the IN()):

1 – Removed names of parameters from call in iReport – possibly confusing the issue …

2 – Make iReport PARAMETER:
CLINSTAGEGROUP_MULTI
Type:
java.util.Collection

3 – On the Jasperserver at:
/usr/local/jasperreports-server-cp-4.5.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/security-config.properties
Turned off security.validation.sql.on :

security.validation.sql.on=false

This gets rid of 6626 error when install & run the iReport with the array/collection parameter.

4 – Download & install fn_Split() on the SQL Server:
http://sqlmag.com/stored-procedures/treat-yourself-fnsplit

5 – Install iReport .jrxml file on Jasperserver

6 – Create Jasperserver INPUT objects – a query to get the list of clinstagegroup (s), and a INPUT CONTROL of type Multi-Select Query (with parameter name set to CLINSTAGEGROUP_MULTI – so that it recognizes the iReport parameter of the same name).

7 – Set up stored procedure on SQL Server:
The CLINSTAGEGROUP_MULTI parameter is passed into the SQL Server stored procedure and becomes @ClinStageGroup_Multi varchar(4000)

Example query to return resultset to iReport:

SELECT a,b,c, ... n

FROM VW_SpecimenAccessions

WHERE ClinstageGroup

IN(SELECT [value] FROM dbo.fn_split(@ClinStageGroup_Multi, ','))

8 – Can now switch the clinstagegroup (multi)selections on the jasperserver report and bring back appropriate resultsets on the screen.

9 – Over that hurdle – now on to the next …